# Load function in jQuery not loading a txt file

Tags: jquery, html

In my html header I have

```
<head>
<script src="jquary.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     ladda();
    });
</script>
</head>
```

And I load jQuery

and in the body I have

```
<form namne="load"
<fieldset>
    <legend> load</legend>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><div id="innehåll1">vill du ändra denna text</div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<button id="load_text">ändra</button>
</fieldset>
```

and in my Javascript I have written

```
(function($){
   ladda = function() {

$("#load_text").click(function(){
    $("#innehåll1").load("innehåll.txt");
        alert('ändrat');
  });
  };
 })(jQuery);
```

and I have a external txt file by the name innehåll.txt in the same folder that contains:

```
  <h2>fkdösfkds</h2>
  <p>jfksfksdalö</p>
```

My question is, why does the content of the txt file not load in the div tag?

Comment: Even if your swedish, special characters in filenames and variables should be avoided.

Comment: Have you tried just changing "innehåll" to "innehall" everywhere. Also not the typo "jquary.js" at the top

Answer (score 1):

You're not declaring the `ladda()` function as a global function - it's only in scope of the anonymous function you're declaring it inside of - so it's out of scope in your other `$(document).ready()` event handler.

If you check your browser's developer tools you'll likely have a JavaScript error telling you the above. You could just do this:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#load_text").click(function() {
            $("#innehåll1").load("innehåll.txt");
            alert('ändrat');
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: @JosefCarlsson You could do `window.ladda = function() { ... }` to solve the scoping issue, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that may be causing the unexpected behavior:

1. You may try to avoid special characters in the file names
2. You should declare the ladda in the scope you can access in the `ready` function
3. You have to avoid the misspelling in the jQuery in the `form` tag and all the others

Hope this helps you!

The code for defining the function in the right scope:

```
function ladda() {   
  $("#load_text").click(function(){
    $("#innehåll1").load("innehåll.txt");
    alert('ändrat');   
  }); 
}
```

you can also do it directly on the ready body:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#load_text").click(function() {
    $("#innehåll1").load("innehåll.txt");
    alert('ändrat');
  });
});
```

Comment: the txt page that's now called innehall.txt is not loading when pressing the button load_text

Comment: have you tried to access the file itself using the url bar? To check if it is accessible?

Comment: Try to execute this and check if the request was successful:

$("#innehåll1").load("innehåll.txt", function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});

Comment: do you have to have an css?

Comment: it says load is preformed but the text isn't changed